# UK business visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel

I have applied for a business visitor visa for the UK. I have mentioned in my form that my wife would accompany me during the trip. I have not received any answer about the application. I have the following questions:

1. Is it advisable to apply for her visa before knowing the status of my application?
2. What visa category should she apply for?
3. What things need to be taken care of during the visa application?

Comment: Item 3 is rather broad. The form will be the same one you used, General Visitor Visa. What else did you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Your wife would apply for the same [UK Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) as you did (which replaced a number of categories, including Business visitor in 2015). However, you may wish to wait for your visa decision before proceeding with that of your wife as there are no fee refunds for unsuccessful applications.

Her application would be similar to yours, other than purpose, and would include similar documentation as was provided in your application (e.g., financial, employment, leave, previous travel, etc.).